# UIPageViewController transition from control on child UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController, which has two UIViewControllers they are set up as follows:

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self

    let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-10)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

In one of the Child view controllers, I have a button which should transition to a specific index in the PageViewController:

```
    @IBAction func createClick(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let pageViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController") as! UIViewController
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [secondViewController]
    pageViewController.self.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

No errors, but the page does not transition. I'm thinking there is an issue with the delegation, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't actually setting the `viewControllers` property on the `UIPageViewController` that your app is actually using - you are instantiating an entirely new `UIPageViewController` from the storyboard that has no relation to any of the controllers that are appearing on your screen.

One solution is to create a reference to your `UIPageViewController` in each of your child view controllers, like this:

```
weak var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
```

In your `dataSource`, when you implement your "after" and "before" methods, i.e.: `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` you will need to create the new child view controller, and then set the `pageViewController` property to a reference to the "parent" `UIPageViewController`.

Then, when your `@IBAction` method is invoked, you call the method on the `pageViewController` like this:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController") as! UIViewController
let viewControllers: NSArray = [secondViewController]
pageViewController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Something like that ought to work.